# Meteor and React not output data correctly.

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

So I am trying to output some data about paint and all I am getting is [object,object]. I tried adding .toString() but no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I know that this means that there are objects inside of my arrays but I don't even know what is generating the array and/or how to reformat that.

```
class PaintPage extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    //Brads cool
}

handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    Paint.insert({
        brand: this.refs.brand.value,
        color: this.refs.color.value,
        sheen: this.refs.sheen.value,
        room: this.refs.room.value
    });
}

render() {
    var paintArr = Paint.find().fetch();
    paintArr.map((room, index) =>
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xs-2">
                <li className="list-group-item text-center" key={room}>
                    {paintArr}
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>
    );

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-xs-4">
                    <ProductNav />
                </div>
            </div>
            <form className="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-4" />
                    <div className="col-xs-4">
                        <label htmlFor="brand" className="input">
                            Paint Brand
                        </label>
                        <div className="field">
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                name="brand"
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Brand/Company"
                                ref="brand"
                                value={this.props.value}
                                onChange={this.props.onChange}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-4" />
                    <div className="col-xs-4">
                        <label htmlFor="color" className="input">
                            Color
                        </label>
                        <div className="field">
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                name="brand"
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Color"
                                ref="color"
                                value={this.props.value}
                                onChange={this.props.onChange}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-4" />
                    <div className="col-xs-4">
                        <label htmlFor="brand" className="input">
                            Sheen
                        </label>
                        <div className="field">
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                name="brand"
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Sheen"
                                ref="sheen"
                                value={this.props.value}
                                onChange={this.props.onChange}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-4" />
                    <div className="col-xs-4">
                        <label htmlFor="room" className="input">
                            Room
                        </label>
                        <div className="field">
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                name="room"
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Room"
                                ref="room"
                                value={this.props.value}
                                onChange={this.props.onChange}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-12"> </div>
                    <input
                        className="btn btn-primary btn-lg button-buffer"
                        type="submit"
                        value="Input"
                    />
                </div>
            </form>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <ul className="list-group">
                        {paintArr.toString()}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default PaintPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the whole array because you use the variable `{paintArr}` instead of the current element of the map function. It should be like this (assuming you want to print color):

```
var painter = Paint.find().fetch();
    paintArr.map((entry, index) =>
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xs-2">
                <li className="list-group-item text-center" key={entry.room}>
                    {entry.color}
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

Note that also `key={room}` is now `key={entry.room}` because room is an attribute of the current element in the array.

If you still don't know what is going on here, you may further research into the [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function and how it works.